# Get a substring from multiline file

Tags: bash

I have a file with this content :

```
# Disabling this option will break firewall functionality that relies on
# stateful packet inspection (e.g. DNAT, PACKET_FILTER) and makes the firewall
# less secure
#
# This option should be set to "1" in all other circumstances
LF_SPI = "1"

# Allow incoming TCP ports
TCP_IN = "20,21,22,25,53,80,110,143,443,465,587,"

# Allow outgoing TCP ports
TCP_OUT = "20,21,22,25,53,80,110,113,143,443,465,587,"

# Allow incoming UDP ports
UDP_IN = "20,21,53,111"

# Allow outgoing UDP ports
# To allow outgoing traceroute add 33434:33523 to this list 
UDP_OUT = "20,21,53,113,123,111"
```

I need to get the text between `TCP_IN = "`and `,"` at the end of that line.

I tried `ALLOWEDPORTS=$(sed -e 's/.*TCP_IN = \"\(.*\)TCP_OUT.*/\1/' csf.conf)` but I am getting the entire file.

I also tried `ALLOWEDPORTS=$(sed -e 's/TCP_IN = \"\(.*\)TCP_OUT/\1/' csf.conf)` but I got the entire file too.

Any help? I need to get `20,21,22,25,53,80,110,143,443,465,587,` assigned to the variable.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: @anubhava, added that to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```
out=$(sed -n 's/.*TCP_IN = "\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' file)

echo "$out"
```

```
20,21,22,25,53,80,110,143,443,465,587,
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU grep:

```
$ inports=$(grep -Po 'TCP_IN = "\K[^"]*' infile)
$ declare -p inports
declare -- inports="20,21,22,25,53,80,110,143,443,465,587,"
```

`-P` enables Perl compatible regular expressions (required for the `\K`), and `-o` retains nothing but the match; `\K` is a variable-length positive look-behind ("match everything until here, then throw it away"), and `[^"]*` matches characters other than double quotes.

---

The reason that you get the whole file with your commands, by the way, is that sed by default prints every line, even if it doesn't operate on them. To suppress that behaviour, use the `-n` option as in [anubhava's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52183061/3266847).